# ValidationExpression Number positive and negative Decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net

I apologize for my bad writing, English is not my first lenguage.

i need to regex for this

Good

```
-1000000.00  = 7 digits and 2 decimals with negative
-100
1000000.00
100
```

Bad

```
-10000000  = 8 digits
100.000  = 3 decimals
-100.000  = 3 decimals
```

tnx for the help.

Comment: Have you tried something already? Could you edit your question and add your code in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.  Should allow for an optional minus sign, 0 - 7 numeral digits and an optional dot with 2 digits after:

```
^[\-]?[0-9]{0,7}([\.][0-9][0-9])?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use following Regex for validating your number and decimal

```
          Regex : (-)?[0-9]{0,7}(\.[0-9]{2})?
```

And You can see demo [Here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) for regular Expression